# How can I use Android with Java and a core made with Scala?

Tags: java, android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I made a small project using Scala (SBT + IntellijIDEA) that provides me a set of classes and other functions that I want to use in Android. I will call this project $core.

So, keeping that in mind I tried to first only use scala. I tried to create an Android Project using android-plugin and I got it.

But what I really want is to use my $core in an Android Project AND expand the $core classes using Java. $core provides an API that I would like more people to use and they probably don't know Scala so Java would be perfect. Besides, I need to go into a safe route with Android. I saw some info that scala takes a lot of time to compile into Android and has some limitations (like with parceblles).

I already tried to use the classes in eclipse with the import class folder option. I even tried to generate a jar so at least I would have a way to run it and no success. Always the NoClassDef error when I try to use one class from the $core. I have tried to import also the scala compiler library, but didn't work out aswell...

Core isn't finished yet and I would like to develop on a single environment that allowed me to debug on the android device. How can I setup all of this?

PS: Changing to eclipse now maybe is better? Never tried android on intellijIDEA and In scala I can't debug over there, at least using ScalaCheck...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are getting an noclassdeffound error when working with Scala code from java because you didn't add the Scala library to the java project or at least included the party of it that it's used in the Scala code in the jar?

Could you post the rest of the error?

Comment: What do you mean by the rest of the error? The NoClassDef I usually got is something like:

`NoClassDefError : some.package.AClass was not found` AClass was a class that I tried to use in Java that was defined in Scala

Answer (score 0):

You could package the core to .jar together with Scala library, use Proguard to remove all unused Scala library classes from it, and then use that jar as a regular library.